# Bracket Access in Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm trying to get the following code from scala-js/test/src/test/scala/scala/scalajs/test/jsinterop/DictionaryTest.scala to run in the Browser in a Scala.js project.

```
import scala.scalajs.js

val obj = js.eval("var dictionaryTest13 = 
     { a: 'Scala.js', b: 7357 }; dictionaryTest13;")
val dict = obj.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[js.Any]]
var propCount = 0
var propString = ""

for (prop <- js.Dictionary.propertiesOf(dict)) {
  propCount += 1
  propString += dict(prop)
}
// g.console.log(...)
```

It gives me: java.lang.RuntimeException: stub

How can I get this to work and make use of bracket access, e.g. to run through a json Object given from js to scala.js, in analogy to the js pattern: for(i in obj) {obj[i]} ?

That serves the trivial purpose to iterate in a over json datastructure in a way that is not bound to specific attributes.

Comment: What Scala.js version are you using to compile the code?

Comment: I'm using 0.4-SNAPSHOT to build a fork of scala-js-example-app, which itself uses 0.1-SNAPSHOT in build.sbt.

Comment: You might want to bump that to `0.4.1`. I can't reproduce any of your issues. But the RTE saying "stub" suggests that your compiler isn't in sync with your library. (`js.Dictionary.propertiesOf` is a compiler primitive, if it fails like this, the compiler didn't replace it).

Comment: Could you try with a stable version, e.g., 0.4.0 or 0.4.1 (which are more recent than 0.4-SNAPSHOT).
Also, could you provide a stack trace? Your browser should be able to give you that with the dev tools, or you can catch the exception and use `printStackTrace()` to display it on the console.

Comment: With stable version 0.4.0 the exception is: scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing - which seems to be self-explanatory. So the question is: How can I provide the missing implementation? Where ist the starting point - is a javascript implementation missing?

Comment: After updating to stable version 0.4.0 and compiled to javascript it works now in the browser! On the scala sbt-scala-console in the same project it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah great! It is not supposed to work in the sbt-scala-console, since this one uses a JVM, which cannot execute Scala.js code. (Put differently: there is no working REPL for Scala.js.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussion:

The OP's code works with Scala.js 0.4.0 in the browser. However, it does not work in the REPL (through sbt), since Scala.js does not support the REPL.

The sbt plugin will issue a warning in the future if the REPL is used.